# #include <regex.h> for problems with creating correct regexp

Tags: c++, regex

I would like to grab everything before `]` in `aasd{123;'asd'aaaa]asd`. So I tried to create regex but `regex.h` works weird.

Closest I get: `".*[^\\]]"` which gives me: `aasd{123;'asd'aaaa]`

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){


    const char* phrase = "aasd{123;'asd'aaaa]asd";
    const char* expression = "........"; // <- what should be here? 

    size_t group_size = 5;
    regmatch_t *pmatch = new regmatch_t[group_size];
    memset(pmatch, 0, sizeof(regmatch_t) * group_size);

    regex_t regex;

    int reti = regcomp(&regex, expression, REG_EXTENDED);

    if (reti){
        cout << "Error1" << reti <<endl;
        return false;
    }

    reti = regexec(&regex, phrase, group_size, pmatch, 0);
    if (reti){
        cout << "Error2 " << reti <<endl;
        return false;
    }

    int len = 0, i = 0;
    char result[10000];

    for (i = 0; pmatch[i].rm_so != -1; i++){
        len = pmatch[i].rm_eo - pmatch[i].rm_so;
        memcpy(&result, phrase + pmatch[i].rm_so, len);
        cout << "num " << i << " " << result << endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[^\\]]*` is what you are looking for.

In english: from the start of the line (`^`) match everything which is not a "]" (`[^\\]]*`).

---

**UPDATE**

There must be an odd quirk to this library, `^[^]]*` passed the test.

The `"^[^\\]]*"` literal get complied into `^[^\]]*`. This should have been an escaped `]` in a character class `[]`, but this library turned it into a character class containing not `\` followed by any number of `]`s.

`^ [^\] ]*` instead of `^ [^\]]*`.

Fortunately, there is an alternate form which allows for `[]]` to match `]` if it's the only character in the character class. This extended to `[^]]` to match a non `]`.

In short… try `^[^]]*`.

Comment: Just paste your regexp in my code as `const char* expression = "^[^\\]]*";`

Comment: @zie1ony heh, odd quirk of this library. I updated my answer.